# Parsing in to a recursive data structure

Tags: f#, fparsec

I wish to parse a string in to a recursive data structure using F#.  In this question I'm going to present a simplified example that cuts to the core of what I want to do.

I want to parse a string of nested square brackets in to the record type:

```
type Bracket = | Bracket of Bracket option
```

So:

- "[]" -> `Bracket None`
- "[[]]" -> `Bracket ( Some ( Bracket None) )`
- "[[[]]]" -> `Bracket ( Some ( Bracket ( Some ( Bracket None) ) ) )`

I would like to do this using the parser combinators in the FParsec library.  Here is what I have so far:

```
let tryP parser = 
    parser |>> Some
    <|>
    preturn None

/// Parses up to nesting level of 3
let parseBrakets  : Parser<_> = 

let mostInnerLevelBracket = 
    pchar '[' 
    .>> pchar ']'
    |>> fun _ -> Bracket None

let secondLevelBracket = 
    pchar '['
    >>. tryP mostInnerLevelBracket
    .>> pchar ']'
    |>> Bracket

let firstLevelBracket = 
    pchar '['
    >>. tryP secondLevelBracket
    .>> pchar ']'
    |>> Bracket

firstLevelBracket
```

I even have some Expecto tests:

```
open Expecto

[<Tests>]
let parserTests = 
[ "[]", Bracket None 
    "[[]]", Bracket (Some (Bracket None))
    "[[[]]]", Bracket ( Some  (Bracket (Some (Bracket None))))  ]
|> List.map(fun (str, expected) -> 
    str
    |> sprintf "Trying to parse %s"
    |> testCase
    <| fun _ -> 
    match run parseBrakets str with
    | Success (x, _,_) -> Expect.equal x expected "These should have been equal"
    | Failure (m, _,_) -> failwithf "Expected a match: %s" m
)
|> testList "Bracket tests"

let tests = 
[ parserTests ]
|> testList "Tests"

runTests defaultConfig tests
```

The problem is of course how to handle and arbitrary level of nesting - the code above only works for up to 3 levels.  The code I would *like* to write is:

```
let rec pNestedBracket = 
    pchar '['
    >>. tryP pNestedBracket
    .>> pchar ']'
    |>> Bracket
```

But F# doesn't allow this.

Am I barking up the wrong tree completely with how to solve this (I understand that there are easier ways to solve this particular problem)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for FParsecs `createParserForwardedToRef` method. Because parsers are values and not functions it is impossible to make mutually recursive or self recursive parsers in order to do this you have to in a sense declare a parser before you define it.

Your final code will end up looking something like this

```
let bracketParser, bracketParserRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Bracket>()
bracketParserRef := ... //here you can finally declare your parser
    //you can reference bracketParser which is a parser that uses the bracketParserRef
```

Also I would recommend this article for basic understanding of parser combinators. https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators/. The final section on a JSON parser talks about the `createParserForwardedToRef` method.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - will mark as the answer once I've had a chance to work through it.

Answer (score 4):

As an example of how to use `createParserForwardedToRef`, here's a snippet from a small parser I wrote recently. It parses lists of space-separated integers between brackets (and the lists can be nested), and the "integers" can be small arithmetic expressions like `1+2` or `3*5`.

```
type ListItem =
    | Int of int
    | List of ListItem list

let pexpr = // ... omitted for brevity

let plist,plistImpl = createParserForwardedToRef()

let pListContents = (many1 (plist |>> List .>> spaces)) <|>
                    (many  (pexpr |>> Int  .>> spaces))

plistImpl := pchar '[' >>. spaces
                       >>. pListContents
                       .>> pchar ']'
```

P.S. I would have put this as a comment to Thomas Devries's answer, but a comment can't contain nicely-formatted code. Go ahead and accept his answer; mine is just intended to flesh his out.