# How to parse recusrive grammar in FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

Previous questions which I could not use to get this to work

[Recursive grammars in FParsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186230/recursive-grammars-in-fparsec)

- Seems to be an old question which was asked before `createParserForwardedToRef` was added to FParsec
- AST doesn't seem to be as horribly recursive as mine.

[Parsing in to a recursive data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218632/parsing-in-to-a-recursive-data-structure)

- Grammar relies on a special character `'['` to indicate another nesting level. I don't have this luxury

I want to build a sort of Lexer and project system for a language I have found myself writing lately. The language is called q. It is a fairly simple language and has no operator precedence. For example `1*2+3` is the same as `(1*(2+3))`. It works a bit like a reverse polish notation calculator, evaluation is right to left.

I am having trouble expressing this in FParsec. I have put together the following simplified demo

```
open FParsec

type BinaryOperator = BinaryOperator of string
type Number = Number of string

type Element =
  |Number of Number
and Expression = 
  |Element of Element
  |BinaryExpression of Element * BinaryOperator * Expression

let number = regex "\d+\.?\d*" |>> Number.Number

let element = [ number ] |> choice |>> Element.Number

let binaryOperator = ["+"; "-"; "*"; "%"] |> Seq.map pstring |> choice |>> BinaryOperator

let binaryExpression expression = pipe3 element binaryOperator expression (fun l o r -> (l,o,r))
let expression =

  let exprDummy, expRef = createParserForwardedToRef()
  let elemExpr = element |>> Element
  let binExpr = binaryExpression exprDummy |>> BinaryExpression
  expRef.Value <- [binExpr; elemExpr; ] |> choice
  expRef

let statement = expression.Value .>> eof

let parseString s =
  printfn "Parsing input: '%s'" s

  match run statement s with
  | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Ok: %A" result
  | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Error: %A" errorMsg

//tests
parseString "1.23"
parseString "1+1"
parseString "1*2+3" // equivalent to (1*(2+3))
```

So far, I haven't been able to come up with a way to satisfy all 3 tests cases. In the above, it tries to parse `binExpr` first, realises it can't, but then must be consuming the input because it doesn't try to evaluate `elemExpr` next. Not sure what to do. How do I satisfy the 3 tests?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Have you tried FParsec's [operator precedence parser](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/operatorprecedenceparser.html)? Even though you don't have precedence, it still makes things a lot easier in your case. Unless you're coding this for learning purposes.

Comment: I have not tried the operator precedence parser. Will take a look. Also, this is not just for learning purposes. My preference is to go with the simplest code that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meditating on [Tomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195421/3760519), I have come up with the following that works

```
let expr, expRef = createParserForwardedToRef()
let binRightExpr = binaryOperator .>>. expr
expRef.Value <- parse{
  let! first = element
  return! choice [
      binRightExpr |>> (fun (o, r) -> (first, o, r) |> BinaryExpression)
      preturn (first |> Element)
    ]
}

let statement = expRef.Value .>> eof
```

The reason the first parser failed is given in the [FParsec docs](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-alternatives)

> The behaviour of the <|> combinator has two important characteristics:
>
> <|> only tries the parser on the right side if the parser on the left
> side fails. It does not implement a longest match rule.
> However, it only tries the right parser if the left parser fails without consuming input.

Probably need to clean up a few things like the structure of the AST but I think I am good to go.